# Why lodash cloneBuffer function use buffer.slice when isDeep flag is true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, lodash

Here is the loadsh [source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.internal/cloneBuffer.js):

```js
function cloneBuffer(buffer, isDeep) {
  if (isDeep) {
    return buffer.slice()
  }
  const length = buffer.length
  const result = allocUnsafe ? allocUnsafe(length) : new buffer.constructor(length)

  buffer.copy(result)
  return result
}
```

As we can see, if the `isDeep` flag is `true`，`cloneBuffer` function use `buffer.slice()` to copy the buffer.

But accord to the Node.js slice's documents:

> Returns a new Buffer that references the same memory as the original

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_slice_start_end

And `Buffers and TypedArrays` documents:

> While TypedArray#slice() creates a copy of part of the TypedArray, Buffer#slice() creates a view over the existing Buffer without copying.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarrays

Which said it clearly, `Buffer.slice` **just creates a view over the existing Buffer**, and **without copying**.

so why lodash use it to do the cloneDeep operation?